# RestAssured groovy.json.JsonException

Tags: json, rest-assured

I am trying to create a test to validate the response of a JSON Post is as expected.

I am trying to test the POST of a JSON message body to a URL which is turn then sends a text message and if successful it sends a response that it was successful again in JSON format.

My test is as follows

```
public void simpleTest() {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("phoneNumber","353837986524");
        jsonObj.put("messageContent","test");

        given()
                .port(31111) // port number
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(jsonObj.toString())
                .when()
                .post("/testing/services/text/send")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .body("message", equalTo("{\"resultMessage\":\"Message accepted\", \"messageID\":\"0123456\"}"));
    }
```

but i'm getting the following exception

```
groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'R', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.

    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:85)
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:96)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:82)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parseText.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ContentParser.parse(ContentParser.groovy:41)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ContentParser$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:583)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:760)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:251)
    at com.jayway.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:234)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:264)
    at ie.david.text.flow.Test1.simpleTest(NoNumberSpecifiedTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Which is weird because the first character is not "R"

I originally didn't use JSONObject and had the code as 
`String myJson = "{\"phoneNumber\":\"353837986524\", \"messageContent\":\"test\", \"clientApp\":\"30711\", \"transactionId\":\"20100101-DL123-353875213464\"}";`

But was still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error code, it looks like that your JSON is corrupt, use a JSON validator to check it. If not, it is likely a Restassured issue. What happens if you just use .body(jsonObj) instead of the .toString()? I think it will solve the issue, but I am not sure.